# Set ':authority' header in Postman

Tags: http, cookies, https, postman, authority

I'm currently trying to replicate a https request with the following headers.

[image]

The authentication is based on a Session Cookie.
However, there is also a header field called `:authority`,
which I'm not able to replicate in Postman.

[image]

Also, couldn't I find any solution for that problem
or what exactly the `:authority` header means on the Internet.
This header seems to be required, as I'm getting a 400 error code back
as soon as I send my replicated request.

[image]

I've proxied the request sent from Postman and can confirm that the only difference at the first glance is the missing `:authority` header.
Thanks ^^

Answer (score 1):

Alright, taking a closer look at the `Raw` Request, I noticed that the actual header is called `Host` and is mapped in the UI to `:autority`. Now its working. cheers

[image]